# Web-scraping a-tag nested inside div-tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I just want to extract all the five a-tag data list of card which is nested the div tag as shown in the picture. How could I extract it?

[image: HTML CODE]

I have tried this one,

```
btag = []
for data in soup.find_all('div', id="mosaic-provider-jobcards"):
  for atag in data:
     atag = soup.find_all('a').append(btag)

print(btag)
```

but it showed none. Can anyone help?

Comment: What does `print(data)` output?

Comment: you overwrite `atag` in loop and also append an empty list to a list of all `a` tags, based off `soup`, each time.

Comment: @arsho it print none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors:

```
soup.select('#mosaic-provider-jobcards > a')
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Comment: I have tried this, it works. But why the len is only showed 4? If you can see, there are 5 a-tag in the code.  Means there are 5 cards there.

Comment: @xkderhaka the last card seems to be different from the others (some kind of ad?). Are you sure it's actually present in your downloaded page content? Ads usually get rendered  using JavaScript.

Comment: i can agree with you when i saw the id is kind different from the 4 top which started with job rather than sj. thank you!